# How to Insert Add To Calendar link to email template .erb Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, outlook, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I send email to some user, and I would like to add link / button 'Add to calendar', that will add the ICS event automatically to the recipient calendar (google, outlook etc.).

Currently, I am creating ICS calendar event by the gem and send to mail by defined the `content_type: 'text/calendar'` and `body: ical.to_ical`.

I would like to send the email without defined the above and add link / button 'Add to my calendar' that will be added to the recipient calendar (google, outlook etc.) dynamically.

Can someone have an idea how to do it?

**UPDATE:**
I have added link to google calendar that creates dynamic URL for creating google calendar event (https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE..),

But I still don't know how to build this link for outlook that will open create new event in outlook.

Comment: Have you tried "Add by URL" option in google calendar.

Comment: Hi @StephenM, do you mean add link to google.com/calendar... that add dynamic?
I mean, add links specific for Google, Outlook etc.?

Comment: Hi @StephenM, I succeed to add link that redirect to create new event in google, but still not in Outlook. 
How should I do it for outlook?

Comment: In outlook there is an option "Add Calendar" , from that option you can add via "From internet" option.

Comment: @StephenM, I know. But I would like to add link to email template that will do this Add to calendar.
Is there any way to add to calendar from internet by link in outlook?

Comment: You can create a link for outlook web/owa/live, docs are here: https://github.com/InteractionDesignFoundation/add-event-to-calendar-docs/blob/master/services/outlook-web.md

Comment: OR you can attach .ics file to the email (but it's not very dynamic, right?). Unfortunately email clients don't support data-links (like `data:text/calendar;charset=utf8,BEGIN:VCALENDAR%0d%0aVERSION:2.0%0d%0aBEGIN:VEVENT%0d%9%0d%0aSUMMARY:UXinsight 2019%0d%0aDTSTART;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20190403T090000%0d%0aDTEND;TZID=Europe/Minsk:20190404T190000%0d%0aDESCRIPTION:UXinsight%0d%0aEND:VEVENT%0d%0aEND:VCALENDAR`)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [add_to_calendar](https://github.com/jaredlt/add_to_calendar) gem.

```
# create new instance, adding your event attributes
@cal = AddToCalendar::URLs.new(
        start_datetime: Time.new(2020,12,12,13,30,00,0), 
        title: "Christmas party!", 
        timezone: 'Europe/London'
      )

# access 'add to calendar' URLs
@cal.google_url
#=> "https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=Christmas%20party%21&dates=20201212T133000/20201212T143000&ctz=Europe/London"

@cal.office365_url
#=> "https://outlook.office.com/calendar/0/deeplink/compose?path=/calendar/action/compose&rru=addevent&subject=Christmas%20party%21&startdt=2020-12-12T13:30:00Z&enddt=2020-12-12T14:30:00Z"
```

Note that it's a separate link for each calendar (Google vs Outlook) so you would need to provide each link and user would click on the right one.

Disclaimer: I wrote the gem :)